# Using OpenGL on QT without the wrappers

Tags: api, qt, opengl, wrapper

I'm looking for a GUI toolkit to use in conjunction with OpenGL. QT looks promising but unfortunately it wraps most OpenGL functions in QT classes. Is there any way for me to create an OpenGL 3.3 context in QT and just use the standard C API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for you to use most of the QT specific OpenGL classes. You need the QGLWidget context itself, something to tell QT when to repaint the widget (that can just be a timer that calls updateGL() on your QTGLWidget 60 times a second) and the event handling. Just make a class that inherits from the QGLWiget and put your C-type OpenGL code in the paintGL() function.

If you want some sample code:
https://github.com/dcbishop/g3test
check in src/Application/QT*

Comment: Thanks. Your code seems handy. I guess I'm still having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around how an OpenGL context is initialised. I'm sure I'll make more sense soon.

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting such errors when compiling your code: CMakeFiles/g3test-qt.dir/src/Renderable/DemoScene.cpp.o: In function `Program::getUniformBlockIndex(char const*) const':
/home/rickert/Workspace/g3test/src/Renderable/../OpenGL/Program.hpp:94: undefined reference to `glGetUniformBlockIndex'

Answer (score 1):

The QopenGL widget gives you the context, you then simply override the initialiseGL, paintGL methods and you can use raw openGL calls directly.

The Qt wrappers around PBO and VBOs are convenient to save doing all the manual DLL loading on  Windows but aren't really necessary