# Is there anyway to use the OpenGl API directly in Qt 5?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

We're using Qt 5.01. We're supposed to use OpenGl to write a visualizer. Even a simple function to draw a triangle returns the error: glBegin() not found, glVertex2f() not found/defined or something.

I learned this is because Qt 5 doesn't come with the regular OpenGl API but it has its own QOpenGl framework.

Is there anyway to eschew the QOpenGl framework and work with OpenGl directly?

I'm on a Windows system using MinGW if that's relevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using OpenGL on QT without the wrappers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796444/using-opengl-on-qt-without-the-wrappers)

Comment: I don't know about that, but you can create an OGL window with something like GLFW, then pass the `HWND` to QT IIRC.

Comment: Your assumption is totally wrong, and more than likely it's because you are not using GLEW, and/or your project isn't set up correctly to find the OpenGL headers/libraries.

Comment: Which Qt build are you using? If you're using the pre-built binaries, this might be relevant: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23499 I.e. you might need to recompile Qt to have opengl configured as needed.

Comment: @cmannett85 In my .pro file, I'm using Qt+= opengl and including QOpenGl in my header files. Do I need any more?

Comment: This question needs more details, like the actual code that's causing the problem. Otherwise it's impossible to know what's wrong.

Comment: *"Is there anyway to eschew the QOpenGl framework and work with OpenGl directly?"* - Well, yeah, just use it. I.e. include the neccessary headers and link to the neccessary libraries (and any possible additional libraries for extension management) like with any other OpenGL project, just using Qt for context management. It's not that QtOpenGL forbids the usage of plain OpenGL functions. But if you don't know how to setup a non-Qt OpenGL project, then *that* would be the point where to start.